# Why useradd -m doesn't fill created home dir with some defaults?

Tags: users, useradd

**My motives:**

I want to create deployment script which prepare all system with just 1 click, and although learn Linux this way. So I don't want to use interactive utils like `adduser` (all interaction info I put in some settings.txt).

**My system:**

Debian 8.2 (jessie)

**I want:**

Create user account with home directory and default folders inside. Like `adduser` do but with `useradd`.

**My problem:**

There is paragraph in `man userradd`:

> ```
>    -m, --create-home
>        Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and directories contained in the
>        skeleton directory (which can be defined with the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.
> ```

I looked in /etc/adduser.conf to find the value of SKEL variable for `adduser`. And it is /etc/skel.

But after I run some `useradd -m myuser -k /etc/skel`, I've got empty /home/myuser directory.

**Update 1**

After I created some additional file, it alsought copied to the new user home directory (with 3 hidden files). So it means that /etc/skel doesn't impact on such folders as: Desktop, Downloads, etc. But in this case what does?

Comment: The directories you are referring to are part of the `xdg-user-dirs` I think, and are specific to "desktop" environments: IIRC they are created by the system when the user first instantiates an appropriate Xsession, based on the templates in /etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults

Answer (score 3):

When a new home directory is created by `adduser` or `useradd`, the home directory is populated with the contents of `/etc/skel` (the "skeletal home directory", see `man adduser` and/or `man useradd`).  This directory contains the initial dot-files, like `.bashrc` etc., that all users get.  The `Desktop` etc. directories are *usually* not part of the contents of she skeletal home directory since a user may not even want to run a desktop environment (or one that uses those directories).

These directories are created when the user logs in and starts a graphical desktop environment.

Would you want these extra directories (or any other file or directory) to be part of the skeletal home directory, then create them in `/etc/skel`, assuming the user's graphical desktop environment does not have issues with these directories already existing (I don't use Linux-like desktops, so I don't know).

Answer (score 1):

For me , by default, the /etc/skel contains just 3 hidden files, `.bash_logout` , `.bashrc` and `.profile`, which can be displayed with `ls -a`.
Your command should work, have you checked the content of your /etc/skel directory ?

Comment: I although found 3 hidden files inside /etc/skel. (post updated)

Comment: You have to create the folders/files in `/etc/skel` .  For example, I created `/etc/skel/Desktop/test.sh` and for the new user, the folder `/home/myuser/Desktop` was created containing the `test.sh` file .